# How does YUI3 loader decide to append "?" to the configured comboBase

Tags: javascript, yui

I am setting up an application that uses the YUI loader for combo loading. My config looks like:

```
{
    ...
    comboBase: "/locationWhereIHostYui3/YComboHandler.axd?",
    ...
    groups: [
        {
            ...
            comboBase: "/app1/Combo?"
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I have several different comboBase paths because I am loading js files from a handful of different applications. The strange thing is how YUI handles the various comboBase paths. For example, with my top-level path, it produces URLs like:
    /locationWhereIHostYui3/YComboHandler.axd?/path/To/Yui/File/1.js&/path/To/Yui/File/2.js...

Because of the way this is formatted, the individual combo'd file paths do not get URL-encoded.

However, with my group comboBase paths, I get:

```
/app1/Combo??[url-encoded path 1]&[url-encoded path 2]...
```

Note the extra '?' and the url encoding. Seeing this, I tried removing the '?' from my group combo base paths, but that produced:

```
/app1/Combo/path1&/path2...
```

Thus, I now get no '?' at all!

Can anyone explain how to set this up correctly? I can, of course, apply URL-decoding in my combo service but I'd like to understand the right way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this cheat-sheet gist I made myself a while ago will help?

https://gist.github.com/tivac/1374920

Comment: I'm confused, does that actually explain where the extra '?' is coming from?

Comment: Down-voted for now, since as far as I can tell this does not answer the question